# How to measure instantaneous download rate when streaming a video in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

How to measure instantaneous download rate when streaming a video in silverlight ?

Comment: We need more info to answer that... What are you using to play video, what kind of measure do you need, should the measure be embedded in your app or only a debug feature, etc...

Comment: And of course, you should accept some answers if you want more of them...